# How to highlights different color in a specific x Axis in MP Android chart Library

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

[the line chart using MP Android chart Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uZoK.jpg)  
in the given images, i want to highlights different color in line of Wednesday only, or any given specific x axis

Comment: Just trying to clarify the question - you want to have a different color for the points on Wednesday, right?

Comment: yes, on wednesday